# Send image using socket without saving it

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have tried with saved image file (is worked) and then I have tried to send just the bytes of the image (I don't want to save the image) and got error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
```

This is my code:

```
frame = self.newFrame()
fm = BytesIO()
frame.save(fm, 'jpeg')
with open(fm, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        si = f.read(1024)
        if si:
            self.conn.send(si)
        else:
            break
```

How you can see I tried to use BytesIO to demo file but is not work like I want to... And I don't have idea how to send bytes without using `open()` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open `fm`, as it's in memory already. Just seek to beginning of buffer with `fm.seek(0)` and write it to socket as you do already.